# IIS | PHP Error: No input file specified

Tags: php, iis

im running IIS 7.5 / PHP 7.0 CGI. If i open a **non exist** .php file i get this error:

> No input file specified.

IIS don't use the 404 Error Page, like in .html files. I found some solutions, for example set **doc_root** in php.ini or comment out **open_basedir** .. but it won't help.

Comment: Sounds more like a server configuration issue than a coding issue. Try asking over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) instead, or just Google on _"set custom 404 page on IIS 7.5"_

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: IIS 7 > Site > Handler Mappings > Edit handler > Request Restrictions > Mapping tab > Check "Invoke Handler only if request is mapped to:" > Select "File or folder"